# Find all the Instances of a Scriptable Object and store it in a List

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have one Scriptable Object `Character` and let us say n instances of that `Character`.

`Character.cs`

```
public class Character : UnityEngine.ScriptableObject
{
...
}
// Let us say that there are 100 instances of this Class
```

Now I create another Class

`CharacterList.cs`

```
public class CharacterList
{
     List<Character> characterList = new List<Character>();
     FindObjectsOfType<Character>();

     // I also tried to write Character[] character = FindObjectsOfType<Character>() but that did not work.
// Now How do I put all the objects found in the List?
}
```

What I want to do is create a `Class` that isn't a `Monobehaviour`. Just a simple Class called `CharacterList` and in there I want a `List` of Characters that will contain all the instances of the `Character` Scriptable Object. Hence, there should be n number of Characters in `CharacterList`

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Isn't ScriptableObject singular? I mean that all Character are pointing to the same shared ScriptableObject. As a result you'd have a list of items all pointing to the same place

Comment: show us what you've tried already. Then we can help you with the next step

Comment: I just want to store all the instances of the ```Character``` Scriptable Object that I have created in a ```List``` of ```Character``` objects. Let us say that I have created 100 instances of ```Character``` Class, then I want to store all those 100 instances of ```Character``` in that ```List```. Now the List is in another Class cakked ```CharacterList```. So whenever I want to see an Item of the list, I will have to write ```CharacterListInstance.ListName[i]```

Comment: I added what I've already tried.

Comment: I typed ```object[] characters = FindObjectsOfType(typeof(Character));``` in the ```CharacterList.cs``` Class to solve the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(SO = Scriptable Object)
We've 2 options here. Depending if these SO are serialized or instantiated during play.

### Option 1 - SO are serialized

Easier option is to create another monobehaviour or scriptable object and place all the instantiated object there.

```
public class CharacterList : ScriptableObject
{
     public Character[] characterList;
}
```

The other way will require you to search for the SO in the assets folder by scripting using [AssetDatabase.FindAssets](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.FindAssets.html) and [AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath.html).

In this case the code will look like this:

```
public class CharacterList
    {
        List<Character> characterList = new List<Character>();

        void PopulateList()
        {
            string[] assetNames = AssetDatabase.FindAssets("Your_Filter", new[] { "Assets/YourFolder" });
            characterList.Clear();
            foreach (string SOName in assetNames)
            {
                var SOpath    = AssetDatabase.GUIDToAssetPath(SOName);
                var character = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<Character>(SOpath);
                characterList.Add(character);
            }
        }
    }
```

How to find them.

**VIA NAME**
You can replace "Your_Filter" to retrieve your SO. In this case the SO should share come kind of commonality in their names.

**VIA FOLDER**
You can replace new[] { "Assets/YourFolder" } with your folder. In this case all the SO should be in the same folder AND this folder should contain ONLY these SO.

### Option 2 - SO are instantiated

In this case I would suggest to implement some kind of factory.

Instead of creating the SO with the usual code:

```
ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<YourSo>();
```

I would use a factory the Create the Instance and store it.
So you will have something like this.

```
public static class CharacterGenerator
{
     static List<Character> characterList = new List<Character>();

     public static Character CreateCharacter()
     {
          var character = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<YourSo>();
          characterList.Add(character);
          return character;
     }
}
```

So whenever you want to create a new character you will call `CharacterGenerator.CreateCharacter();`

Remember also to Clear the list at the start of the game (or when you think it is required).

Comment: `ScriptableObject`s are assets, not components or gameobjects that are "instantiated" in the way you're describing. Using `ScriptableObject.CreateInstance` creates a new asset in the project hierarchy in the same way that the context menu will create a `Material`. If you create an asset in this fashion and add it to the character list, it will not show up on the next run (since it is already created). See [Unity's documentation on ScriptableObject.CreateInstance](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScriptableObject.CreateInstance.html)

Comment: [CreateInstance is not always suggested](https://forum.unity.com/threads/should-i-call-scriptable-objects-createinstance-during-runtime.637915/) but it is an option. From [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/understanding-scriptable-objects.471306/#post-3072879) I read SO instantiated in memory 'cease to exist when you exit play mode'. This is also what happens in my experience.

Comment: Then that's a misunderstanding of the documentation on my part. I see there's a line that's important in the page I linked: "To easily create a ScriptableObject instance **that is bound to a .asset file** via the Editor user interface, consider using CreateAssetMenuAttribute". I guess that would mean the OP would need to instantiate every character on each play to use these objects. Why not use asset files and drag them to the `CharacterManager` line of `Character[]`?

Comment: If the SO will be few it can be a choice. But if they are many it can be tricky.If they are created using CreateAssetMenuAttribute you can surely drag them, but it's a bit risky. I expect someone would forget to drag one of them sooner or later (and if you create a new Character later you might forgot to add to the list). I agree it's better to have some kind of auto retriever .

Comment: I wanted to add something. the filter input can include types ("t:MySOType") that'll limit the array to only objects of that specific type resulting in a typed filtered array, meaning the searched folder doesn't have to ONLY have a specific types in it and can have other things that will be filtered out by that filter. Didn't test that myself yet :) . So you can even do something like AssetDatabase.FindAssets("t:" + nameof(MyCharacterSO), new[] { someFolderPath });

Comment: If you already have the reference MyCharacterSO, you do not need to retrieve it. Also nameof would return the name of the class and not the name of the file. To actually filter them you need to catch them first and then check them against something like a string regex (for naming), or checking them with the `is` keyword. You would have something like `if (AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath(assetPath, typeof(Object)) is T yourScriptableObject) { itemsFound.Add(yourScriptableObject); }`

Answer (score 0):

In the `CharacterList.cs` Class:

```
object[] characters = FindObjectsOfType(typeof(Character));
```

Comment: `Object.FindObjectsOfType [...] It will return no assets (meshes, textures, prefabs, ...)` https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html

Comment: In that case, will ```Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll``` work?